# Jquery object is undefined after sort but is in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I do an ajax call to a script that returns data.  I see the data in firebug and it is correct.  When the data comes back I do a sort and it works too.  I see in firebug the object is sorted the way I want.  After the sort I try to access a key/value pair.  I see in firebug that the key/value I want is in the object.  When I try to use the object key/value to assign to a var it is undefined.  I'm trying to aggregate repeating data.  If I'm not using the best way to do it, please help me with a better method.

data sample

`coreDate   "060115"
coreType    "asterisk_11"
fileName    "/var/www/html/Cores/gdb.hamid.asterisk.060115"
jid         "hamid"`

code

```
    $.when (
            $.ajax( {
                    type:"GET",
                    url: 'cf.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 120000,
            })
    )
    .done(function(coreInfo) {
            coreInfo.sort(function(a,b) { return a.coreType > b.coreType } );
            var coreStats={};
            coreStats.numOfCores=0;
            coreStats.numOfCoreType=0;
            coreStats.prevCoreType=coreInfo.coreType;
// for some reason coreInfo.coreType is not defined.  The coreInfo object exists and coreType is there.  I tried this.coreType but is undefined.
            $.each(coreInfo, function() {
                    coreStats.numOfCores++;
                    if (coreStats.prevCoreType != this.coreType) {
// This works.  why do I have to access this.coreType instead of coreInfo.coreType?
                            $('#list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td><a href="'+this.fileName+'">'+this.coreType+'</td><td>'+coreStats.numOfCoreType+'<br>core</td><td>jid</td></tr>');
                            coreStats.numOfCoreType=0;
                    }
                    coreStats.numOfCoreType++;
                    coreStats.prevCoreType=this.coreType;
// setting prevCoreType works here
            });
            $('#cores').html("<h1>"+coreStats.numOfCores+"</h1><br>Core Files");
    })
    .fail(function() {
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code and description, it sounds like `coreInfo` is an array of objects, is that right? If it were an object, it wouldn't have a `sort()` method and your code would stop right there.

If it's an array, it doesn't have a property like `coreInfo.coreType`. Each *element* of the array is an object with `coreType` and other properties. That's why you are able to access `this.coreType` inside the `$.each()` callback. `$.each()` iterates through the array, element by element, and passes each individual element into the callback.

Where it looks like you're seeing `coreInfo.coreType` in Firebug outside the `$.each()`, I suspect that what you're actually seeing is `coreInfo[0].coreType`, i.e. the first element of the array.

To help keep track of whether a variable is an array or not I strongly suggest giving arrays names that reflect this fact: either a plural word, or add `List` or `Array` to the name, or something. A name like `coreInfo` sounds like a singular item. I would call the array `coreList`, `coreArray`, or simply `cores`. Personally I like plural words for brevity: `cores` for the array of core info, `core` for an individual element in that array.

This way when you see `cores.coreType` or `coreList.coreType` or `coreArray.coreType` it will *look* wrong.

BTW for much more readable code, I suggest never using `this` in a `$.each()` callback. Instead, use named parameters.

```
$.each( coreInfo, function( i, core ) {
    coreStats.numOfCores++;
    if( coreStats.prevCoreType != core.coreType ) {
        $('#list > tbody:last-child').append(
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                    '<a href="' + core.fileName + '">' +
                        core.coreType +
                    '</a>' +  // MISSING IN ORIGINAL
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    coreStats.numOfCoreType +
                    '<br>core' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    'jid' +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
        coreStats.numOfCoreType = 0;
    }
    coreStats.numOfCoreType++;
    coreStats.prevCoreType = this.coreType;
});
```

Note that there was a missing `</a>` in your markup in the code above. It's much easier to spot an error like this if you indent the markup strings in the same way that you might indent raw HTML code, instead of cramming it all onto one line.

A minor point: You don't need to wrap `$.ajax()` inside `$.when()`. `$.ajax()` returns a Promise that you can use directly.

You don't need the code that computes `coreStats.numOfCores`. You can simply use the `length` property of the array. If you follow my suggestion to call the array `cores` you could do this:

```
$('#cores').html( "<h1>" + cores.length + "</h1><br>Core Files" );
```

Finally, your `sort` callback function has a bug and will not sort the array properly. It may have worked in a simple test case, but it will fail to sort other arrays. It has to handle all three cases: `<`, `==`, and `>` and return an appropriate value for each case, perhaps like this:

```
coreInfo.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return(
        a.coreType < b.coreType ? -1 :
        a.coreType > b.coreType ? 1 :
        0
    );
});
```

To verify my assumptions, can you post an example of your actual JSON data, not a formatted table?

Comment: here is the raw unformatted json returned from the script`[{"coreDate":"050415","jid":"dspillman","coreType":"runBrowser_11","fileName":"\/var\/www\/html\/rhcCores
\/coreFiles\/050415\/dspillman`\/gdb.log.runBrowser_11.20150504.dspillman_CORE_040515-1202"},{"coreDate"
:"050415","jid":"ssamari","coreType":"mdMgr_10","fileName":"\/var\/www\/html\/rhcCores\/coreFiles\/050415
\/ssamari\/gdb.log.mdMgr_10.20150504.ssamari_CORE_040515-1208"},

Comment: Yup, as you can see from the `[` at the beginning, this is an *array* of objects as I was guessing.

Comment: coreInfo is the returned json.data.  I was thinking it's an object.  If it is an array, is that the default behavior or did I mess something up?  I'll take your advice on names.  You got me on the missing </a>.  It was a doh! moment.  Originally I had formatted the code the way you suggested to debug.  After I 'thought' I got it right I compacted it and still missed </a>.  I'll update the sort function too.  Your comment was very helpful for me sending down the correct path.  I'll try to access the first coreType in the list by using the array index and see if that works.

Comment: With `coreInfo` being an array, everything is working as expected, nothing you messed up other than trying to access `coreType` and other properties on the entire array instead of on an individual array element.